# Google Map API is Extremely Slow

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I'm setting up a dynamic Google map on all of the pages on the site to show the locations you can see on every page to help users understand the locations.

It works, but works EXTREMELY slow, so slow that if it has about 40+ it can take around 1 minute to load the map and if it's more locations than that on a page it just get stuck and does not load the map.

Here is a link to see the map:
http://www.exchange-currency.org/wakefield/

And Here's the code as it is on the website, you can also see the code with view source but note the addresses are from a string with php, you can see the output on the view source of the page.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?q=<?php the_title(); ?>&key=AIzaSyDeyknfWm0qmejgXZh_VXihNcHbidewODQ"></script> 

 <script type="text/javascript">
  var delay = 10;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng();
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: latlng,
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  function geocodeAddress(address, next) {
    geocoder.geocode({address:address}, function (results,status)
      { 
         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var p = results[0].geometry.location;
          var lat=p.lat();
          var lng=p.lng();
          createMarker(address,lat,lng);
        }
        else {
           if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
            nextAddress--;
            delay++;
          } else {
                        }   
        }
        next();
      }
    );
  }
 function createMarker(add,lat,lng) {
   var contentString = add;
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
     map: map,
           });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
     infowindow.open(map,marker);
   });

   bounds.extend(marker.position);

 }
  var locations = [<?php echo $locationAddresses; ?>];
  var nextAddress = 0;
  function theNext() {
    if (nextAddress < locations.length) {
      setTimeout('geocodeAddress("'+locations[nextAddress]+'",theNext)', delay);
      nextAddress++;
    } else {
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
  }
  theNext();

</script>
```

What can I do to make it work in a normal speed so its actually usable?

Here's a link to a page with more locations so you'll see what I'm talking about:
http://www.exchange-currency.org/montreal/

Thanks!

Edit:

Also if there is a way to make it load async and with clusters instead of multiple markers that would be great, can't seem to get it figured out =/

Comment: I tried that, for some reason when I do that the entire thing stop working =/

Comment: I'm not sure I got it right, I've added geocodeAddress to the callback it now looks like this:   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?q=<?php the_title(); ?>&callback=geocodeAddress&key=AIzaSyDeyknfWm0qmejgXZh_VXihNcHbidewODQ"></script>      Is this what you meant? it still loads slowly

Comment: I tried, I'm probably doing something wrong, when I do that the map stop working.